# Impossible to retrieve files from an FTP in WinSCP - Bad message

Tags: ssis, ftp, winscp

I use WinSCP 5.17 to retrieve files from an FTP, when I retrieve files from the root folder of the FTP all works, but as soon as I try to retrieve the files from the sub-folder it doesn't work.

Here is the instruction I use:

```
get /Clients/Folder2/Folder3/*.* F:\folder1\folder2\
```

and this is the error message:

> Error listing directory '/Clients/Folder2/Folder3'.
> Bad message (badly formatted packet or protocol incompatibility).
> Error code: 5
> Error message from server: Bad message

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, I generated the script from WinSCP GUI and it works.

```
open ftps://username:password@ftp-adresse.azure.com/ -certificate="ee:5f:af:7c:26:6b:bb:6f:cd:86:6a:2c:03:1e:8f:ab:e7:63:fd:43" -rawsettings FollowDirectorySymlinks=1
cd /Clients/folder2/folder3
lcd "F:\folder1\folder2"
get "*.xlsx"
exit
```

Comment: OK, so the problem probably was that the server has case-sensitive file system. So you have used a wrong path `.../Folder2/Folder3`, while the correct path is `.../folder2/folder3`